# check duplication of two 2-dimensional-list algorithm?

Tags: java, list, algorithm, optimization, multidimensional-array

Two List<List<string>> are given (referred to as a and b).

it returns: Map<List<string>, List<List<string>>>

- let the items of a, b them a1, a2, a3,... and b1,b2,b3...
- Select only items with overlapping strings ​​among the elements of b1 and a1 (List<string>)
- Enter key = b1, value = a1 in result.

ex)

```
Define a and b as follows:
a = [a, b, c], [d, e, f], [a, d, f]
b = [a, d], [a], [c], [x]

it returns : 
key        value 
[a,d]    | [a,b,c],[d,e,f],[a,d,f] 
[a]      | [a,b,c],[a,d,f] 
[c]      | [a,b,c] 
[x]      | empty list
```

In reality, the length of the list in a and b will exceed at least 100,000.
I tried this method using the List.contains, but time complexity was O(n^3) at the worst case.
Here is my code, I want to reduce the time complexity of that algorithm below O(n^2).

```java
 public Map<List<String>, List<List<String>>> compute(List<List<String>> a, List<List<String>> b) {

        Map<List<String>, List<List<String>>> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (List<String> elem : b) {
            result.put(elem, a.stream().filter(e -> e.stream().anyMatch(elem::contains)).toList());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What _will exceed at least 100,000_: the length of _a_, the lengths of _a1, a2, a3,..._, both? Same for _b_?

Comment: How many different individual strings are in _b_? (In your example, there are four: a, d, c, x.)

Comment: a and b will be almost identical. However, the length of each item is mostly less than 10.
The string is just an example and could be in the thousands.
Maybe there is no same string per item.

Comment: I didn't ask about _same string per item_, but rather in the whole _b_ altogether, i. e. is there a considerable amount of strings occurring in multiple items of _b_ (as does `a` in your example)? - The answer must be yes, since you mention only thousands of strings and at least 100,000 items, right?

Comment: right, My goal is to find all lists that contain at least one item.

Comment: Your statement _My goal is to find all lists that contain at least one item_ is confusing, not only because it has nothing to do with my preceding question, but also since before you denoted as _item_ the things like _b1,b2,b3..._, i. e. _item_ is a list of strings. Did you rather mean _My goal is to find all lists that contain at least one string from an item_?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'll modify it soon

Comment: No big deal, it was only a comment after all; the question itself seems clear enough in this respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a way to reduce it to below `O(n^2)` but to reduce it to `O(n^2)` we can reduce `List.contains` `O(n)` by `HashMap.get` which is `O(1)` time complexity.

The suggestion is instead of checking `contains`, we find the indexes of elements in list `a`, and `b` elements will get that indexes and get the corresponding list of `a`.

Firstly, build a `Map` containing elements of `a` as key and value as its indexes.

```
    Map<String, Set<Integer>> aInSet = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        for (String elem : a.get(i)) {
            Set<Integer> elementSet = aInSet.getOrDefault(elem, new HashSet<>());
            elementSet.add(i);
            aInSet.put(elem, elementSet);
        }
     }
```

Here is the output of `aInSet`, now we have the index list of elements belonging to.

```
a=[0, 2], b=[0], c=[0], d=[1, 2], e=[1], f=[1, 2]
```

Then we combine the indexes of a list of elements in `b` to get the corresponding in `a`.

Ex for `[a, d]`, we have a combined set `[0, 1, 2]`. Here is the code

```
    Map<List<String>, List<List<String>>> result = new HashMap<>();

    for (List<String> elem : b) {
        Set<Integer> elemSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (String elemB: elem) {
            elemSet.addAll(aInSet.getOrDefault(elemB, new HashSet<>()));
        }
        List<List<String>> listContainElem = elemSet.stream()
            .map(a::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        result.put(elem, listContainElem);
    }
```